# Passing 2D string array (non-blittable) from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, string

The issue is passing a 2D string array (non-blitable) from managed C# to unmanaged C++. 
I not sure if the DllImport and MarshalAs conventions are fully correct for this type of string array. Maybe, the pointer / memory allocation definition has a missing attribute. Many thanks for your comments.

```
public struct TestStruct
{
   public string[,] stringArray;
}

[DllImport("C:\\Users\\Win32Project2.dll",
    EntryPoint = "DDentry",
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]

    public static extern void DDentry
    (
        [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray,
        ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string[,] arrayReadDat, int iDim1, int iDim2
    );

    private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestStruct arrayReadDat = new TestStruct();
        arrayReadDat.stringArray = new string[lastRow+1, lastCol+1];

        for (int i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= lastCol; j++)
            {
                arrayReadDat.stringArray[i, j] = i;
            }
        }

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TestStruct));
        IntPtr strPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(arrayReadDat, strPointer, false);

        DDentry(arrayReadDat.stringArray, lastRow+1, lastCol+1);

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(strPointer);
     }
```

Here the unmanaged C++ code, which don not show the data from the C# code:

```
  _declspec(dllexport) void DDentry(string *p2DIntArray, int iDim1, int iDim2)
  {
     int iIndex = 0;
     for (int i = 2; i <= iDim1; i++)
     {
        for (int j = 1; j <= iDim2; j++)
        {
           arrayREAD[i][j] = p2DIntArray[iIndex++];
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a litlle mistake while copying: it should be :string strK = "testify";
arrayReadDat.stringArray[i, j] = strK;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, that instead of importing the DLL in C++ code and exporting it in C# code, You are doing it exactly vice versa.

An example how to call a managed DLL from native Visual C++ code can be found here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736

It is written for VS2005, but the overall logic should be same in newer VS versions also.

Comment: Actually, the direction worked perfectly with 2D integer and double arrays using "DllImport" on the C# side and "_declspec (dllexport)" on the C++ side.

Comment: In that case, try char* instead of string in C++ side

Comment: No, it's not working .. empty arrays only on the C++ side.